# Check the state validity of a Spring proxied bean without try-catch

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, proxy-classes

I have a bean being created by a service with the following class:

```java
@Configuration
public class AccessManager {

    @Bean(name="access", destroyMethod="destroy")
    @Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Autowired
    public Access create(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        return new Access();
    }

}
```

Everything works as expected, except that when the application is starting, this method is being called, probably because I have some other singleton beans that use the `Access` bean. At the start up there is no request bound to the Thread, and it's expected to get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when trying to access any property of the `request` parameter.

No problem. **The question is**, is it possible to check if the underlying **`HttpServletRequest`** of the proxy **`request`** is **`null`** before calling a property that raises the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [RequestContextHolder#getRequestAttributes()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes%28%29). That will return `null` if you're not currently in a context where request scope could be used.

```
@Configuration
public class AccessManager {

    @Bean(name="access", destroyMethod="destroy")
    @Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    @Autowired
    public Access create(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() != null) {
            System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        }
        return new Access();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is with separation of concerns. Usually your service layer should not have any dependency on the servlet classes. This is very much a controller/UI concern.

Your service class should be provided with the properties which it needs to do its job. In this case a String. This service method should be called from a controller method which is injected with the servlet request.

Something like the following:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private AccessManager accessManager;


  @RequestMapping
  public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    accessManager.create(request.getRemoteAddr());
  }
}
```

and your service would then look like this:

```
@Service
public class AccessManager {

  public Access create(String remoteAddress) {
    return new Access();
  }
}
```

To sum up, anything annotated as @Service shouldn't have access to the Request.

Comment: The interest bean here is the `Access` itself. I thought `AccessManager` only as the "bean factory" responsible for building `Access`'s session beans. And for this task, it needs the request object. O inject the `Access` bean instead of the `AccessManager` to the my `@Controller`'s. Is this wrong? The `AccessManager` is not interesting to any of my controllers.

Comment: Anyway, the above situation is only a example. I have others points on the code where a proxied bean is used and I'd like to check if the underlying object is in a valid state without using a `try-catch` to achieve it.

Comment: My point is that anything annotated as Service shouldn't have access to the Request.

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. I just changed from `@Service` to `@Configuration`. The Request is necessary for the bean instantiation to seek for values inside it (the domain, for example). As the `Access` bean is session-scoped, it will always have a request bound to the Thread.

Comment: You say there will always be a request bound, it it's an @Configuration class which is loaded on app startup there will be no request available. Hence you won't have anything to inject.

Comment: But will be no asks for an Access bean, too, as they're session-scoped. Except for the initialization of the `@Controller`s, and this will cause an `IllegalStateException`, which I'd like to avoid as there is nothing to do.

Comment: There is no error at the application at all. The problem is that during the start up, it's instantiating an `Access` bean, I don't know why, and it shouldn't as it is session-scoped. Anyway, as this instance is not supose to exists, it could be securely discarded. The problem is that this would cause an `IllegalStateException` if I try to access the instance. I'd like to prevent the exception by checking the bean state validity. Is it possible or I do need a `try-catch`?